# Not able to install ng CLI on macOS Sierra

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I did a clean install of macOS Sierra yesterday, when I tried installing ng CLI I got this error.

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging'
```

I have tried to do `sudo uninstall`, `npm clean cache`, and re-install but with no luck. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix the error by using [option 2 in the NPM documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions):

> **Option 2: Change npm's default directory to another directory**
>
> There are times when you do not want to change ownership of the
>   default directory that npm uses (i.e. `/usr`) as this could cause some
>   problems, for example if you are sharing the system with other users.
>
> Instead, you can configure npm to use a different directory
>   altogether. In our case, this will be a hidden directory in our home
>   folder.
>
> 1. Make a directory for global installations:
>
>    ```
>    mkdir ~/.npm-global
>    ```
> 2. Configure npm to use the new directory path:
>
>    ```
>    npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
>    ```
> 3. Open or create a `~/.profile` file and add this line:
>
>    ```
>    export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
>    ```
> 4. Back on the command line, update your system variables:
>
>    ```
>    source ~/.profile`
>    ```
>
> Test: Download a package globally without using `sudo`.
>
> ```
>     npm install -g jshint
> ```
>
> Instead of steps 2-4 you can also use the corresponding ENV variable
>   (e.g. if you don't want to modify `~/.profile`):
>
> ```
> NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global
> ```